# How to terminate SQL statements when using DEFAULT value and OleDB?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb, jet

Using C# and the JET OleDB driver (`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`) to connect to an old Access database (think Access 97). The following SQL statements work fine:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyInt] Integer DEFAULT 3
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyString] Text(30) DEFAULT hello
```

But terminating the statement with a semi-colon (;) causes problems:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyInt] Integer DEFAULT 3;  -- syntax error
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyString] Text(30) DEFAULT hello; -- default is now "hello;"
```

Can SQL statements with `DEFAULT` be terminated?

Comment: Must run these statements separately as two independent actions.

Comment: If I insert a space just before the semi-colon, both of those last 2 statements work fine when executed from `CurrentProject.Connection` in an Access application session.  But that just seems bizarre to me.

Comment: I am using VBA, not C#, and Access 2010. Tried that and fails. But why two ALTER statements? Multiple fields can be added with one ALTER action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default values can (and probably should) be quoted using double quotes to avoid these errors, among others:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyInt] Integer DEFAULT "3";  
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyString] Text(30) DEFAULT "hello";
```

Note that Access doesn't support executing multiple statements at once, so there's really no reason to terminate statements. They terminate at the end automatically.

Alternativly, add a trailing space after the literal. The `DEFAULT` clause is followed by a literal, which is either enclosed in quotes and ends on the closing quotes, or ends on the following whitespace.

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyInt] Integer DEFAULT 3 ;
```

Comment: Actually, do NOT enclose value for numeric type field in quote marks.

Comment: @June7 Why not?  `DEFAULT` follows rules for literals, not expressions, so you won't set a string as the default. Try it, you'll see it works properly (as long as executed over an OLEDB connection or in ANSI compatible mode, so `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER etc`.) You can also see this when you set 1+3 without quotes as the default for a text field, that literal text is used, while when you use it in a query that's an addition and a number.

Comment: I did try (but with apostrophes) and ended up with a default of `'3'` in the property for number field. Then I tested without apostrophes and the default is simply `3`.

Comment: @June7 Those are the wrong quotes. Only double quotes work for literals. I've edited the answer to be a bit more explicit and provide a bit more context.

Comment: Tested with embedded double quotes and the result is `"3"`. Again. works without embedding quotes or apostrophes. Can't get query object to work at all with DEFAULT.

Comment: Well, it's not an issue, the database engine processes the defaults correctly. Anyway, you can also use a space if you want to terminate the statement.

Comment: Double-quoting the value worked for me in Access 2010: `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [FunkyInt] Integer DEFAULT ""3"";"`  There are no quotes included in the field's Default Value property.

Comment: Yes, did that and end up with `"3"` in the property. I have Access 2010.

Comment: Tested using C#, .NET 4.5, the Jet OleDB driver, and this old Access 97 database...works with `"`. Both numerical and text fields tested. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, mystery solved. Setting Access to SQL Server Compatible prevented quote marks or apostrophes saved in DefaultValue for number field. And apostrophes worked just as well as quote marks.